# Cron executes while partly ignoring trigger

Tags: cron

There's a problem with my crontab

I set

```
*/5 * * * * /home/money/relaunch.sh
```

in crontab -e

in relaunch.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pgrep -l -x xyz || /home/money/a.sh && /home/money/xyz.sh
```

However, when applying this crontab it launches new instance of xyz.sh every 5 minutes regardless of

```
/usr/bin/pgrep -l -x xyz ||
```

How do I get this right?

Comment: do you know that `-x` is exact match?

Comment: of course, the program itself is named xyz in this case

Comment: so `/home/money/xyz.sh` runs a program called `xyz` - it's not clear from what you posted that would be the case - because, of course, `xyz` is not exactly `xyz.sh`

Comment: sorry i did not make it clear. any way to solve this?

Comment: so, to confirm, there IS a process called exactly `xyz` started by `xyz.sh`?

Comment: yes u are right.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have 2 sequential conditional operators.

```
script1 || script2 && script3
```

The key is to think of the problem backward. Script3 will run when the exit code it receives is 0. Let's analyze the two possible outcomes of running script1.

- Case1. Script1 is successful - it produces exit code 0; script2 is never run; script3 receives the exit code 0 from script1 and runs.
- Case2. Script1 is unsuccessful - it produces exit code 1 (or other non-zero code); script2 is run and exits with code 0; script2 runs again.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I can see two scenarios depending on when you want script3 to run.

1. You want to run script3 only if script2 is successful. Then you should use a [subshell](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

   ```
    script1 || (script2 && script3)
   ```
2. You want to run script2 if script1 fails and script3 if script1 is successful. Then you just change the places of 2 and 3:

   ```
    script1 && script3 || script2
   ```

Comment: I want to run script2 following by script3 in case that script1 fails

Comment: Then the first solution should work for you: "script1 || (script2 && script3)"